# how can I make the input form data appear in HTML

Tags: angular, service

**This error should be simple but I'm new with angular**

**I believe there should be few changes to this code**

**Service Code bellow**

```
import { Grade } from './../calculator/calculator.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Input } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ResultService {
  @Input()
  grade: Grade = {
    name: '',
    grade1: null,
    grade2: null,
    grade3: null,
  };

  calcGrade(): void {
    let nota1 = this.grade.grade1 * 0.25;
    let nota2 = this.grade.grade2 * 0.25;
    let nota3 = this.grade.grade3 * 0.5;

    let conta = nota1 + nota2 + nota3;

    if (conta < 6.2) {
      console.log(
        `o aluno ${this.grade.name} foi reprovado com a nota ${conta}`
      );
    }
    if (conta >= 6.2) {
      console.log(
        `o aluno ${this.grade.name} foi aprovado com a nota ${conta}`
      );
    }
  }

  constructor() {}
}
```

> when I click on a button I want call that component with the data entered in another component

**HTML Code bellow**

**Or I can add the code service into a ts component**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>
      o aluno {{ grade.name }} tirou {{ grade.grade1 }} na primeira prova e
      {{ grade.grade2 }} na segunda prova
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Code HTML of the component A bellow**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Olá Professor
  </div>
  <form class="form" action="submit">
    <input
      [(ngModel)]="grade.name"
      name="name"
      type="text"
      class="inputName"
      placeholder="Nome do Aluno:"
    />
    <input
      [(ngModel)]="grade.grade1"
      name="grade1"
      type="number"
      class="inputGrade"
      placeholder="Nota da prova 1:"
    />
    <input
      [(ngModel)]="grade.grade2"
      name="grade2"
      type="number"
      class="inputGrade"
      placeholder="Nota da prova 2:"
    />
    <input
      [(ngModel)]="grade.grade3"
      name="grade3"
      type="number"
      class="inputGrade"
      placeholder="Nota da prova 3:"
    />
    <a routerLink="/result">
      <button (click)="calcGrade()" class="button">
        Calcular
      </button>
    </a>
  </form>
  <div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the service and a behavior subject to transfer data between components

lets say you need to pass the grade from component A to component B when you click some button in component A

1. we can define that behavior subject in the service,
2. when you click that button in component A, just emit or next the grade info entered
3. In component B, in ngOnInit hook, we can subscribe to that behavior subject, to get that grade info

-in Service

```
// define a new behavior subject to transfer the grade from component A to component B
gradeSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Grade>(null); // set the initial value of this behavior subject to null, you can set it anything you need
```

-in Component A

```
  constructor(private resultService: ResultService) {} // inject the service in component A

  onClick(gradeInput) {
    // gradeInput is an object contains all the properties of the grade
    // design it as you want, maybe you pass name, grade1, grade2, and grade3 manually
    // the most important thing, that we need to pass this object through the behavior subject

    this.resultService.gradeSubject.next(gradeInput);
  };
```

-and in Component B

```
  grade: Grade; // this is the grade object you used in the html

  constructor(private resultService: ResultService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // subscribe the behavior subject from the service to get the grade object

    this.resultService.gradeSubject.subscribe((gradeResult: Grade) => {
      // set the grade property in this component to the gradeResult
      this.grade = gradeResult;
    });

  }
```

hope it helps

---

---

### Update

after checking your codes, here is the solution using the behavior subject as described above

-keep the behavior subject defined in the service

-In calculator.component.ts, we will emit or next the grade to the behavior subject defined in the service, will do that in calcGrade method, as in this method we navigate to the results component

```
calcGrade(): void {
  let nota1 = this.grade.grade1 * 0.25;
  let nota2 = this.grade.grade2 * 0.25;
  let nota3 = this.grade.grade3 * 0.5;

  let conta = nota1 + nota2 + nota3;

  if (conta < 6.2) {
    console.log(`o aluno ${this.grade.name} foi reprovado com a nota ${conta}`);
    // this.router.navigate(['/result']);
  }
  if (conta >= 6.2) {
    console.log(`o aluno ${this.grade.name} foi aprovado com a nota ${conta}`);
    // this.router.navigate(['/result']);
  }

  // here we will emit the grade to the behavior subject
  this.resultService.gradeSubject.next(this.grade);
  this.router.navigate(['/result']); // just do the navigation one time here rather than doing it in all the conditions
}
```

-In results.component.ts, we will subscribe to the behavior subject to retrieve the grade object

```
  ngOnInit() {
    // here we need to subscribe to that behavior subject
    this.resultService.gradeSubject.subscribe((res: Grade) => {
      this.grade = res;
    });
  }
```

Comment: could you create an instance of your project here https://stackblitz.com/, as it's not clear

Comment: link is not found

Comment: my repository - https://github.com/paulorod07/calculator-challenge

Comment: I dont know why link is not found

Comment: no worries mate, I've checked the files, and I've just updated my answer to be identical with your files and logic, could you check that update?, hope it helps now :)

Comment: Great, really glad it's working now, could you accept the answer, so anyone needs some help can find it easily?